# helper method returning a call to itself

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I wanted to eliminate some duplication and came up with something I've not seen so I figured I post it and see if others had.

Using a delegate to allow the method to return another call to itself.

The commented out code is what I replaced.

```
delegate ChainRepositoryCommand ChainRepositoryCommand(Action<Data.Repository> action);
ChainRepositoryCommand RepositoryCommand(Action<Data.Repository> action)
{
    using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
    {
        action(repo);
    }
    return new ChainRepositoryCommand(a => RepositoryCommand(a));
}

public void Register(ISender<T> sender)
{
    RepositoryCommand
        (repo => repo.AddClient(sender.Name, true))
        (repo => repo.AddMessageType<T>())
        (repo => repo.AddRegistration<T>(this.name, sender.Name));
    //using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
    //{
    //    repo.AddClient(sender.Name, true);
    //}
    //using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
    //{
    //    repo.AddMessageType<T>();
    //}
    //using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
    //{
    //    repo.AddRegistration<T>(this.name, sender.Name);
    //}
    sender.Sending += sender_Sending;
}
```

Update: I worked it into my repository class as a static method.  I know this is all probably obfuscating from a clean code standpoint, but it's fun to experiment with new things from time to time.

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    ...
    public delegate Chain Chain(Action<Repository> action);
    public static Chain Command(Action<Repository> action)
    {
        using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
        {
            action(repo);
        }
        return new Chain(next => Command(next));
    }
    ...
}

public class Server<T> : IServer<T>
{
    ...
    public Server(string name)
    {
        serverName = name;
        Data.Repository.Command
            (repo => repo.AddServer(name));
    }

    public void Register(ISender<T> sender)
    {
        Data.Repository.Command
            (repo => repo.AddClient(sender.Name, true))
            (repo => repo.AddMessageType<T>())
            (repo => repo.AddRegistration<T>(this.serverName, sender.Name));
        sender.Sending += sender_Sending;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That... Is rather interesting.  And a little disturbing.

Comment: Your business logic and data access is intermingled, which defeats the purpose of repository pattern.

Comment: to which business logic are you referring? I admit I tend to think of a Repository as a general purpose wrapper around a data context...

Answer (score 2):

> Using a delegate to allow the method to return another call to itself.

You don't necessarily need a delegate to allow another call to itself. For example:

```
public class SimpleCalculation
{
    private int result;

    public int Result
    {
        get { return result; }
    }

    public SimpleCalculation Add(int i)
    {
        result += i;
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleCalculation Subtract(int i)
    {
        result -= i;
        return this;
    }
}

//Usage:
var sc = new SimpleCalculation();
sc.Add(5).Subtract(2);
Console.WriteLine(sc.Result); //Writes '3' to the screen
```

I'm not saying your code is wrong, only saying that you don't need delegates to achieve this. Also this:

```
//using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
//{
//    repo.AddClient(sender.Name, true);
//}
//using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
//{
//    repo.AddMessageType<T>();
//}
//using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
//{
//    repo.AddRegistration<T>(this.name, sender.Name);
//}
```

Could also be rewritten as:

```
using (var repo = new Data.Repository(true))
{
    repo.AddClient(sender.Name, true);
    repo.AddMessageType<T>();
    repo.AddRegistration<T>(this.name, sender.Name);
}
```

I don't know if you already knew or tried this but I'm just pointing it out as a possibility. But I agree with you: experimenting with code is fun! :)